# React: Add state property to ref object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I just tried to do the following and it's working:

```
const myRef = useRef();

const [myState, setMystate] = useState();
const [myState2, setMystate2] = useState();

myRef.myState = myState;
myRef.myState2 = myState2;
```

and then I pass `myRef` into a child component with `forwardRef()`

### Why?

Because it allows to logically group all related state under one ref object while also not bothering passing additional props.

Is there a reason I shouldn't do that? I couldn't find an answer for such usage of `useRef`.

Answer (score 0):

What if your state changes ? Are you writing extra line of code for side effect ? In order to work like this you need to write extra effect.

```
useEffect(() => {ref.current = {state1, state2}}, [state1, state2])
```

Also react won't render if ref's current value. I think theres no reason to use `ref` here. You can group your states into single props like below.

```js
const [state1, setState1] = useState({a: 1});
const [state2, setState2] = useState({b: 2});
<Child state={{ ...state1, ..state2}}/>

const Child = ({a, b ...props }) => {
    return <p>{a + b}</p>
}
```

Comment: When state changes, the property inside ref changes too.